# How to fix 404 not found when access the route using ajax and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm currently new developer in laravel, I have problem accessing the route, if I tried to click the edit button on my response it gives me error. this error shows on my production, but on my localhost, this error is not shown. my question is why this error is shown?

> "exception":
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",

**Ajax:**

```
$('.news_and_events_edit_btn').on('click',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr("data-content-id-edit");

    $('.news_and_events_hidden_update_id').val(id);

    $.ajax({
        url:'/get_news_and_event_data',
        type:'get',
        data:{content_id: id},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(res) {
            $('#update_news_and_events_title').val(res[0].content_title);
             update_appEditor_news_and_event.data.set(res[0].content_desc);

        },
        error:function(err) {
            console.log(err);

        }
    });
});
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/get_news_and_event_data','CMSController@get_news_and_event_data')->name('get_news_and_event_data');
```

**Error:**

[image: error]

Comment: Your ajax code in blade file ?

Comment: try to add an absolute url in your ajax request to test whether it's still returning 404 or not.

Comment: @kelvinkantaria what do you mean?

Comment: @RajenderVerma what do you mean for absolute url?

Comment: in ajax url test with url: "https://example.com/get_news_and_event_data" replace example.com with your website url, also check if you are not using any prefix in your route if you do then use that in the url

Comment: what's the url generated by the  `url:'/get_news_and_event_data'` just hover over the name on the dev console.you will get the full route there.check if that matches your expected route.

Comment: pass url like {{route('get_news_and_event_data')}} in ajax and pass url in direct browser and check url working or return 404 ?

Comment: this code works ... https://xxxxxxxx/staging_icweb/get_news_and_event_data

Answer (score 0):

change your `route` and `ajax url` with your content_id parameter and than try

**Route**

```
Route::get('/get_news_and_event_data/{content_id}','CMSController@get_news_and_event_data')->name('get_news_and_event_data');
```

**AJAX Call**

```
     $.ajax({
        url:'/get_news_and_event_data/{content_id}',
        type:'get',
        data:{content_id: id},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(res) {
            $('#update_news_and_events_title').val(res[0].content_title);
             update_appEditor_news_and_event.data.set(res[0].content_desc);

        },
        error:function(err) {
            console.log(err);

        }
    });
```

Comment: i already add token on top my document ready ..  $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     }
 });

Comment: why there is need to csrf_token in GET REQUEST?

Comment: sorry it not works, it gives 404 not found. all my ajax function not working even inserting data it shows 404 not found

Comment: so your code may be wrong dubug your code and find out where exact code is break. also check `storage/log/` for latest error log

Comment: i already solve my problem the url that should i need to do is url: ../route  thank yuo everyone guys..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `route` in ajax request  .
It will redirect you to `route` .

```
$.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('get_news_and_event_data') }}",
        type:'get',
        data:{content_id: id},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(res) {
      }
```

For example, I have a code ,

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: "{{ route('SomeUrlHere') }}",
   method: 'get',
   data: {
       id : id
  }
success: function(data){
    if(data) {
         console.log(data);
    }
```

Comment: sorry it not works, it gives 404 not found. all my ajax function not working even inserting data it shows 404 not found

Comment: Do not use datatype:JSON .

Comment: @SoulAiker I have added my example code , please follow that or see documentation https://www.codeinhouse.com/laravel-jquery-ajax-get-and-post-request-complete-tutorial/

Comment: i already solve my problem the url that should i need to do is url: ../route  thank yuo everyone guys..

Comment: It will be helpful if you post how did you solved the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Change the url to something like this.

```
var id = content_id;

$.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::route('get_news_and_event_data') }}/'+id,
        type:'get',
        data:{content_id: id},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(res) {
            $('#update_news_and_events_title').val(res[0].content_title);
             update_appEditor_news_and_event.data.set(res[0].content_desc);

        },
        error:function(err) {
            console.log(err);

        }
    });
```

Comment: sorry it not works, it gives 404 not found. all my ajax function not working even inserting data it shows 404 not found

Comment: i already solve my problem the url that should i need to do is url: ../route  thank yuo everyone guys..

Answer (score 0):

To solved my problem, I found that there is a sub folder, so from url:'/get_news_and_event_data', to url:'/..get_news_and_event_data',

thanks to all